# Locally Finite Cover

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Give a hint to the following problem:

*Let $M$ be a second-countable manifold, $N\subset M$ closed subset, $\Omega\supset N$ its open neighbourhood. Then $M$ has an locally finite cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$, such that all elements of cover, which are intersecting $N$, lie in $\Omega$.*

Is it essentially that $M$ is a manifold, but not (may be "good") topological space?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

All that matters is that $M$ is a [paracompact space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space). If you can use the fact that every locally compact Hausdorff second-countable space is paracompact, then you are done. Otherwise, I don't know what topological tools you have at your disposal.

Comment: As the question is stated right now, paracompactness is not even needed: for any topological space $M$, for any closed $N\subset M$, and for any open $\Omega\supset N$ the cover $\{M\setminus N, \Omega\}$ is as wanted.
Paracompactness is needed if we require $U$ to be an open cover refining a given one (which I guess might be wanted, even if not explicitly stated).